# Is it possible to rescue everyone on the Kobayashi Maru?

Tags: star-trek-bridge-crew

In the first mission (*Prologue: Shakedown*), you're asked to take one final simulated test before you graduate from Starfleet Academy. During the simulation, you arrive in a sector and are hailed by a ship called the *Kobayashi Maru*. The shift is adrift with life support failing and asks you to rescue the 381 people on board. The ship is in the Klingon Neutral Zone, and you'll have to enter the neutral zone to rescue the ship. You're told that entering the neutral zone will be seen an act of aggression by the Klingons and likely result in them attacking you.

Game Spoilers:

> During the mission, this turns out to be true. If you voilate the neutral zone, endless waves of Klingon vessels attack both you and the *Kobayashi Maru*. The scenario ends when one of three things happens: (1) you abandon the *Kobayashi Maru* and the leave the sector, (2) your ship is destroyed, or (3) the *Kobayashi Maru* is destroyed.

Game/Star Trek Universe Spoilers:

> In the Star Trek universe, the *[Kobayashi Maru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru)* scenario is known as a *No-Win scenario*. Recruits are sent through it to test how they handle a situation where, no matter what choice they make, they can't win. However, [some cadets found ways to beat the scenario through cheating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru#James_T._Kirk). The idea of cheating to win the *No-Win Scenario* has [made its way into other Star Trek games as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru#Star_Trek:_Starfleet_Academy).

**Through in-game mechanics, is it possible to rescue all 381 people on the *Kobayashi Maru* and escape the Klingon Neutral Zone?** Or is this meant to be a true *No-Win Scenario* with no way to rescue everyone and escape alive using in-game mechanics?

Comment: This scenario is so famous and from so long ago that I don't think spoiler sections are necessary... it's like adding spoiler sections to a Star Wars movie talking about Vader being Luke's father... I don't even watch Star Trek and I know this.  (Yes, I mentioned Star Wars in a Star Trek thread... I honestly don't know any other Star Trek super famous events.  I also don't watch Star Wars :)